# Change domain name in url bar with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

Is there a way to use `window.history.pushState` or any other js function to change the whole url in the address bar? I haven't been able to remove the root part.

Context: my app is on Heroku and the url looks like http://mywebsite.herokuapp.com and I'd like to make it look like http://mywebsite.com . I can easily change what is after the .com but not what is before :(

Comment: You can only remove the .herokuapp part if you own and host from the domain for `mywebsite`. Otherwise you're stuck with the herokuapp portion assuming you're deploying off of herokue.

Comment: DNS aliasing and that type of thing is done with server config or at the domain registration level. You can't do much in the browser.

Comment: If that would work,... We would live in a phishing-website world. :)

If you don't own the host/root domain and have access to the webserver it isn't possible..

Comment: @oshikryu, according to [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) on Heroku you don't actually need to host outside of Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This would be unsafe.
Consider the following:

1. Click on phishing link: phishing-bank.com
2. Website mimics: your-bank.com and changes url to your-bank.com .

No way the user can tell the difference now, assuming he doesn't analyse the certificate chain.