# Javascript, change URL origin without page reload

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to replace the origin of the URL without reloading the page? Say I am at `www.example.com`, how can I change the URL to be `www.foo.com` or whatever without reloading the page? I tried using `pushState()` and `replaceState()` to no avail. I get an error saying: `Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'foo.com:4041' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://example.com:4041' and URL 'http://foo.com:4041/'`.

For your information. the two URLS are ones which I generated with my `/etc/hosts` file, they simply pass to an express server at `localhost:4041`.

Thanks

Comment: @Mamun the dupe target is not correct for this question, there they are not trying to break SOP.

Comment: This is a different question. I am not trying to simply append onto a URL like adding /foo to bar.com. I am looking to change bar.com completely to another URL without a page refresh.

Comment: A better dupe target would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461691/change-domain-name-in-url-bar-with-javascript but it has no upvoted nor accepted answer... On a phone rn so there might be others valids. And @Tino, this can't be done. Imagine I manage to launch a popup which behaves like your bank's website, and even has your bank's url in the address bar? I'd become pretty rich pretty far (or in prison)

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah, I ended up reading that elsewhere. That makes a lot of sense. I was curious because I am making a recaptcha harvester and need to be able to fake the URL. I was hoping of being able to do that without a page refresh but it's fine honestly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html5 History Api - pushState from a domain to a subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807921/html5-history-api-pushstate-from-a-domain-to-a-subdomain)